# This Object JavaScript

Tags: javascript, this

Good morning in my timezone,

I am reading Javascript book and there is one example where the "this" object could lead to different results from what we are expecting.

```
var name = “The Window”;

     var object = {
          name : “My Object”,
          getNameFunc : function(){
                    return function(){
                             return this.name;
                           };
                   }
};

(object.getName = object.getName)(); // This will return global value "The window"
```

My question is : The "this" and "arguments" variables are fullfilled just when a function is called, so in the above line of code, the assignment is copying the function reference again to the getName variable,so when the function is called the this should point to the "object" object, why  it points to global context ?

Thanks in advance

With best regards

Comment: Ok i already understood, the assigment returns the Function object , so it is the same that invoking a function from global context.
Thanks very much

Comment: I think you example is not complete, `getName` is missing. You can edit your question and you should mark one answer as accepted: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

The value of `this` is often changes in Javascript. Generally speaking: Only when you call the function directly, like `object.getFoo()`, `this` will be what you expect. If you first create a reference to the functions, like `var getFoo = object.getFoo` and then call `getFoo()` it will be called in the context of whatever object you are in. You can even change `this` to whatever you want by using `call` and `apply`. In the example you provided, the no-op assignment is a confusing way to set `this` to `window`.

Maybe you should find a better book ;)